# How to get the total number of pages in the BuddyPress members directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In BuddyPress, the members directory is split into pages. For example, the first 20 members are displayed on page 1, the second 20 members are displayed on page 2 and so on.

So, on a website with 112 members, I would expect there to be a total of 6 pages to the members directory. This will obviously change as new members join the site.

Is there a way to programmatically get the total number of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
<?php echo round((int)bp_get_total_member_count()/(int)get_option('posts_per_page'));?>
```

Comment: The logic looks good to me, although would it be better to use the ceil() function instead of round()?

Comment: oh, I thought about that, but forget to write a comment :) Sure - ceil() will return correct value more often then round :)